# Use Visual Studio to search for a specific string in a column, etc

Tags: c#, excel, full-text-search

I'm new at Visual Studio and I'm trying to make a program where the user can input a full name into a text box, which will search an excel file for the name, and display the contents of the cell to the right of it...  For example

User inputs "John Smith"

Program searches excel file setup like so:

[image: Excel is like this]

Program outputs jsmith9013...

Comment: It works best if you try to code something, and if it doesn't work you ask questions based on your code

Comment: @efekctive The best way to learn is by example in my option. It is better to give an example and have the student correct it for their need. This allows them to have to learn the code in order to make it work. If you don't have much experience than it is hard to come up with something.

Comment: As far as I know the rules of SO do not include teaching.

Comment: @efekctive From the rules. Help others reproduce the problem

Not all questions benefit from including code. But if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some. But don't just copy in your entire program! Not only is this likely to get you in trouble if you're posting your employer's code, it likely includes a lot of irrelevant details that readers will need to ignore when trying to reproduce the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @efekctive Stackoverflow can also be used to ask questions about homework just look at the very bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Look the post has been down voted 5 times. Not by me. So please take your crusade with others. When I reviewed this post there was no effort on the poster part to write anything as it is now. There is no reproducing a problem when "I am trying to make a program". Logging off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import excel dll which works with excel however you need to have excel on the client pc.
You need to add using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; at the top of your code.
Also you will have to add the reference.
Here is how [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx)

You can use the following function which searches for the word test

```
private void SearchText()
        {
            string File_name = "D:\\test.xlsx";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook oWB;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
            try
            {
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(File_name, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,
                    missing, missing, missing, missing);
                oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets[1];
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng = GetSpecifiedRange("test", oSheet);
                if (oRng != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Text found, position is Row:" + oRng.Row + " and column:" + oRng.Column);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Text is not found");
                }
                oWB.Close(false, missing, missing);

                oSheet = null;
                oWB = null;
                oXL.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Any luck? Please mark as answered if I have answered your question.